# Can I buy a domain name for a server I do not own?

Tags: linux, website, domain-name

I'm in charge of a server in my school, I do not own it, but the way we access it (the website in the server) is by entering its IP, Can I buy a domain name for it  without asking for permission even though Im not the owner?

Comment: Technical things aside, don't do this without your schools permission, or better yet, help school officials to obtain a proper domain name for their school that is in no way tied to you.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can, because there's no such thing as a "domain name for a server". Domain names are not attached to servers. You can buy any domain name you want, that's not already owned by someone else, and then map it to any IP address you want. It doesn't matter what, if anything, is currently attached to the Internet on that IP address.

Having said that, if you buy the domain triplehotxxxbabes.com and point it at your school's server then they may not be very happy with you.

Comment: That depends on the school; some Uni of Tech could easily thinks it's just another everyday practical joke.

Comment: It should be also noted that the web container running on the server can be configured to show content only for specific domain names and ips. Many servers running multiple websites are configured this way and you might be unable to access the content with your domain. In that case you would need administrative access to the server or at least test the domain first, eg. by altering your `hosts` file to point the domain name at the server ip.

Comment: Yes, but OP was supposedly the maintainer of this server, so this shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the school already has some official domain. Instead of buying a new domain in your own name, you should ask whether you can obtain a subdomain (`hostname.example.org`) for the server for easy access. That's the most reasonable and a completely free solution.

If there's no domain present, Mike's answer covers everything.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to use a service like no-ip, and get something like mydomainname.ddns.net, which points to the IP of the server. However, there are some additional considerations: 1) are port 80 or 443 open to public, or only internal? Are they only allowing a certain range of IPs (such as the campus lan) to access that ip? etc etc.

But at least with a service like no-ip you would not be paying for anything if it doesn't work.